# Verify fails if a value for eq() matcher is provided by calling a mocked method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, matcher

For example I have the following test (JUnit 4.12, Mockito 1.9.5)

```
public class SomeServiceTest {

    SomeDao someDao = mock(SomeDao.class);
    SomeService someService = new SomeService(someDao);;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        UserModel user = mock(UserModel.class);
        when(user.getName()).thenReturn("name");

        someService.perform(user);

        verify(someDao).someDaoMethod(any(), eq(user.getName()));
    }
}
```

It fails because mockito thinks that method `someDaoMethod` was not called with value returned by `user.getName()`.
But if I replace the last line with

```
String name = user.getName();
verify(someDao).someDaoMethod(any(), eq(name));
```

It passes! So if `name == user.getName()` why then `someDaoMethod(any(), eq(user.getName()))` fails but `someDaoMethod(any(), eq(name))` passes? And is there any way to overcome this without creating local variables?

Bellow are implementations of `SomeService` and `SomeDao`. `UserMode` is simply a JavaBean.

```
public class SomeService {

    private SomeDao someDao;

    public SomeService(SomeDao someDao) {
        this.someDao = someDao;
    }

    public void perform(UserModel user) {
        someDao.someDaoMethod("random", user.getName());
    }
}

public class SomeDao {

    public void someDaoMethod(String id, String name) {
        //...
    }
}
```